# Thread synchronization of Threads created by other Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I would like to have this hierarchy of Threads:

10 threads (let's call them 1-10): each creates 2 threads (let's call these threads created by thread 1 threads 1A, 1B... by second thread 2A, 2B etc.).

1A waits for lockerA as well as 2A, 3A, ...

1B waits for lockerB as well as 2B, ...

I want to achieve, that when 1A gets the lockerA, then 1B will stop waiting for lockerB.

My non-successful try:

```
public void Process10People()
{
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        new Thread(Enter).Start(i);
    }
}

private void Enter(object id)
{
    Console.WriteLine(id + ". wants to enter");
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        lock (lockerA)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(id + ". is in!");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine(id + ". is done");
        }
    }).Start();
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        lock (lockerB)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(id + ". is in!");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine(id + ". is done");
        }
    }).Start();
```

}

But this is wrong because 1A don't have any option to tell 1B to stop waiting. How can I achieve that please?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Does 1b depend on 1a? then why 2 threads? Should there always be only one "b" thread working? all the rest are waiting?

Comment: I try to achieve something like implementation of Semaphore with maximum count = 2 without using actual Semaphore class. A and B represent two ways how to achieve what is desired (in this case only Thread.Sleep(1000) but there will be some other code then).

Comment: So? You have done it - you will always have 2 threads here working (an `A` and a `B`).

Comment: But for each main Thread it will be done twice instead of only once

Comment: And why not using a semaphore?

Comment: I want to show to my students why is semaphore good - that without a semaphore this task would be so difficult (but I want to show that it is achievable :D ) I have some ideas but they are not very elegant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show your students how complex is a semaphore implemantation, you can show them the source code: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/SemaphoreSlim.cs

Alternatively, you could think about a different design.
For example: having 2 threads that read from a queue - this makes no use of a semaphore.

Another option, is to have 10 threads like you did, without the *A* and *B* threads.
Instead, check and increment a counter with a lock in a loop. Like so:

```
public void Process10People()
{
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        new Thread(Enter).Start(i);
    }
}

private void Enter(object id)
{
    Console.WriteLine(id + ". wants to enter");
    while (true)
    {
        lock(lockObject)
        {
            if (this.threadCount < MaxThreadsAllowed) // MaxThreadsAllowed = 2 in your case
            {
                 this.threadCount++;
                 break;
            }
        }

        // Thread.Sleep(100); // Add a sleep if you'd like
    }

    Console.WriteLine(id + ". is in!");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine(id + ". is done");

    lock(lockObject)
    {
        this.threadCount --;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very interesting and useful example